# Get apache.commons.cli.CommandLine as String

Tags: java

I get an Object of type apache.commons.cli.CommandLine passed. Somehow there is no toString() method (org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine does have a toString() method).

Is it possible to get the original command line as a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the original input arguments back from the CommandLine object. The `CommandLine` object only stores what the parser parsed from your input argument list.

If you really want the exact argument list you provided the parser save a reference to the `String[]` you passed in to the Parser.